# How do you replace segments in a line using fileinput

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a program for counting coins and I want to create a mechanism which essentially scans a specifically written text file and is able to calculate whether it has been falsely counted but also will replace the ending segment of the line with either Y for Yes or N for No.

The txt file reads as such:

```
Abena,5p,325.00,Y
Malcolm,1p,3356.00,Y
Jane,£2,120.00,Y
Andy,£1,166.25,N
Sandip,50p,160.00,Y
Liz,20p,250.00,Y
Andy,20p,250.00,Y
Andy,50p,160.00,Y
Jane,£1,183.75,N
Liz,£,179.0,N
Liz,50p,170.0,N
Jane,50p,160.0,Y
Sandip,£1,183.0,N
Jane,£2,132.0,N
Abena,1p,3356.0,N
Andy,2p,250.0,N
Abena,£1,175.0,Y
Malcolm,50p,160.0,Y
Malcolm,£2,175.0,N
Malcolm,£1,175.0,Y
Malcolm,1p,356.0,Y
Liz,20p,250.0,Y
Jane,£2,120.0,Y
Jane,50p,160.0,Y
Andy,£1,175.0,Y
Abena,1p,359.56,N
Andy,5p,328.5,N
Andy,£2,108.0,N
Malcolm,£2,12.0,N
```

as you can see every line is split into 4 segments, I want the fileinput to be able to replace the fourth segment within the specified line.

My program (all the relevant things to see right now) is as follows:

```
class Volunteer:
    def __init__(self, name, coin_type, weight_of_bag, true_count):
        self.name = name
        self.coin_type = coin_type  # a function allowing me to class the data
        self.weight_of_bag = weight_of_bag
        self.true_count = true_count
```

just a simple object system to make things easier for later

```
with open("CoinCount.txt", "r", encoding="'utf-8'") as csvfile:
    volunteers = []
    for line in csvfile:
        volunteers.append(Volunteer(*line.strip().split(',')))
```

just to create a list as well as an object for easier calculations

```
def runscan():
    with open("CoinCount.txt", "r+", encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:

        num_lines = 0
        for line in csvfile:
          num_lines = num_lines + 1

    i = 0
    while i < num_lines:

        ct = (volunteers[i].coin_type)
        wob = float(volunteers[i].weight_of_bag)

        if ct == ("£2" or "2"):
            accurate_weight = float(12.0)
            limit = 10
            bag_value = 10 * 12
        elif ct == ("£1" or "1"):
            accurate_weight = float(8.75)
            limit = 20
            bag_value = 20 * 8.75
        elif ct == "50p":
            accurate_weight = float(8)
            limit = 20
            bag_value = 20 * 8
        elif ct == "20p":
            accurate_weight = float(5)
            limit = 50
            bag_value = 5 * 50
        elif ct == "10p":
            accurate_weight = float(6.5)
            limit = 50
            bag_value = 6.5 * 50
        elif ct == "5p":
            accurate_weight = float(3.25)
            limit = 100
            bag_value = 3.25 * 100
    elif ct == "2p":
        accurate_weight = float(7.12)
        limit = 50
        bag_value = 50 * 7.12
    elif ct == "1p":
        accurate_weight = float(3.56)
        limit = 100
        bag_value = 3.56 * 100

    number_of_bags = wob / bag_value
    print("Number of bags on this is" + str(number_of_bags))

    import fileinput
    line = line[i]

    if number_of_bags.is_integer():
        with fileinput.FileInput('CoinCount.txt',inplace=True) as fileobj:
            for line in fileobj:
                x = line.split(',')
                for w, word in enumerate(x):
                    if w == 3 and word == 'N':
                        print(line[i].replace('N', 'Y'), end='')
                        i = i + 1
                    else:
                        i = i + 1

    else:
        with fileinput.FileInput('CoinCount.txt',inplace=True) as fileobj:
            for line in fileobj:
                x = line.split(',')
                for w, word in enumerate(x):
                    if w == 3 and word == 'Y':
                        print(line[i].replace('Y', 'N'), end='')
                        i = i + 1
                    else:
                        i = i + 1
```

and finally the thing Im having issues with, the scan function.

the issue is specifically within the last few lines of code here (the replacement part):

```
    import fileinput

    if number_of_bags.is_integer():
        target, replacement = ('N', 'Y')
    else:
        target, replacement = ('Y', 'N')

    with fileinput.FileInput('CoinCount.txt', inplace=True) as fileobj:
        for i, line in enumerate(fileobj):
            words = line.rstrip().split(',')
            if line.words[3] == target:
                line.words[3] = replacement
            print(','.join(words))
            i = i + 1

        f = fileobj.lineno()  # Number of lines processed.

    print(f'Done, {f} lines processed')
```

I basically have created a function which goes down each line and calculates the next line down until there aren't anymore lines, the issue with the last part is that I am unable to replace the actual txt file, If I were to run this program right now the result would be a completely blank page. I know that the fix is most likely a simple but tricky discovery but It is really bothering me as this is all that is needed for my program to be complete.

I understand the majority of the coding used but I am very new to fileinput, I want to be able to go from each line and replace the final segment if the segments name (i.e "Y" or "N") given is inaccurate to the actual legitimate segment name as Y is for true and N is for false. Please help, I tried to make sure this question was as easily understandable as possible, please make your example relatable to my program

Comment: Please narrow down your scope, provide a minimal, reproducible example. Neither of us here have time to read through all of your code and try to understand what is happening.

Comment: this is as minimal as I can make it, could you please just let me know what I did wrong in the final part of code I displayed?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, the problem is whether the calculation of the weight is correct or not. So just create another file instead of using `fileinput`. Do you really need it ?

---

***test.csv***

```
Abena,5p,325.00,Y
Malcolm,1p,3356.00,Y
```

---

1. Read the csv and assign some header names
2. Remove the last column, we don't care if it's correct or not, we will calculate the result anyways
3. Gather your calculation function in one method, we will apply this to every row
4. Apply function to every row, if it's correct write "Y" else write "N"
5. Truncate the whole file and write it over

```
import pandas as pd

with open("test.csv", "r+") as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, names=["name", "coin", "weight", "res"])
    del df["res"]

    def calculate(row):
        if row["coin"] == "5p":
            return "Y" if 3.25 * 100 == row["weight"] else "N"
        elif row["coin"] == "1p":
            return "Y" if 3.56 * 100 == row["weight"] else "N"

    df["res"] = df.apply(lambda row: calculate(row), axis=1)

    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    df.to_csv(f, index=False, header=False)
```

---

***test.csv***

```
Abena,5p,325.0,Y
Malcolm,1p,3356.0,N
```

Comment: i understand and it would be a perfect explanation.... if this wasnt for my coursework and the txt file isnt supposed to be tampered with until the process is run. I need a replacement but I just dont know the syntax

Comment: @SixCray Is `fileinput` mandatory ? If it's not, I have edited the code to apply it in the same file.