# How to replace a portion of a line in a file using fileinput?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import fileinput

if number_of_bags.is_integer():
    with fileinput.FileInput('CoinCount.txt',inplace=True) as fileobj:
        for line in fileobj:
            x = line.split(',')
            for w, word in enumerate(x):
                if w == 3 and word == 'N':
                    print(line.replace('N', 'Y'), end='')
                    i = i + 1
                else:
                    i = i + 1

else:
    with fileinput.FileInput('CoinCount.txt',inplace=True) as fileobj:
        for line in fileobj:
            x = line.split(',')
            for w, word in enumerate(x):
                if w == 3 and word == 'Y':
                    print(line.replace('Y', 'N'), end='')
                    i = i + 1
                else:
                    i = i + 1
```

When I run this program, the text file is completely overwritten and all of its contents removed, each line is structured like this:

```
Athena,£2,133.55,Y
```

I want this program to be able to go through each line (hence why the end shows `i = i + 1`) and replace the Y or N if it isn't supposed to be there (if the calculation is incorrect).

How do I edit this code so that it doesn't remove the txt files data?

Comment: I have already answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66681330/how-do-you-replace-segments-in-a-line-using-fileinput). I was waiting for further feedback but you asked a duplicate question again. Please edit your first question according to your needs and remove the duplicate one.

Comment: @BcK: Your answer to the linked question requires the use of the `pandas` module, so is not a general solution. Besides that, the OP explained to you why they didn't accept it.

Comment: @martineau he didn't stated that `pandas` can't be used, he only told that the file should be altered in place and I modified the code. Apart from that, this still does not justfiy him asking the same question twice.

Comment: @BcK: Just because someone doesn't say they don't want `pandas` used doesn't mean that it's OK to do so — in fact they may not even be aware of its existence — so I would assume the opposite unless the OP mentions it in the question.

Comment: @martineau with all due respect, I am definitely not forcing my answer into his throat and do believe some exposure to more elegant solutions might widen anyone's perspective. Otherwise we would still be writing machine code and you would never discover python unless someone mentioned it to you, despite you being not aware of it at all. But apparently they did not assume the opposite. All in all, we digress from the topic of duplicate question and me trying to collaborate with him amaic and reshape my solution if need be.

Comment: @BcK: Point taken. I see folks do what you did frequently here — and sometimes it's effective and but oftentimes it's not. All depends on the OP and the problem. In this case the answer is relatively simple, so I think just showing them how to do it correctly is the best option — as opposed to getting on their case for not accepting an answer you posted to another question they asked a little earlier.

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes with how `fileinput.FileInput` is being used and the processing related to it is being done.

Something must be printed for each line of input if it is to be in the output.
However, after the `x = line.split(',')` the fourth `word` will contain either a `'Y\n'` or a `'N\n'`, so the following `if w == 3 and word == 'N':` or `if w == 3 and word == 'Y':` conditional be never be `True`. This means nothing is ever printed. This is why the result is an empty file.

There's more than one way to fix things. In the code below, the newline at the end of each line is removed with `rstrip()` before splitting it up into separate words. Doing that will make the testing for `'Y'` or `'N'` work so they can be replaced. Then, regardless of whether the word was changed for not, the words are joined back together and a (possibly updated) line is `print`ed.

I also simplified the things so to make the whole thing shorter by not repeating so much of the code for the two possibilities.

```
import fileinput


if number_of_bags.is_integer():
    target, replacement = 'N', 'Y'
else:
    target, replacement = 'Y', 'N'

line_to_process = 4

with fileinput.FileInput('CoinCount.txt', inplace=True) as fileobj:
    for line in fileobj:
        words = line.rstrip().split(',')
        if fileobj.lineno() == line_to_process:  # Only process the Nth line.
            if words[3] == target:
                words[3] = replacement
        print(','.join(words))

    numlines = fileobj.lineno()  # Number of lines processed.

print(f'Done, {numlines} lines processed')
```

Comment: when I use this code it edits the text file to make all of the lines N instead of Y or N, please help

Comment: Yes, that is what is does — because that's what the code in your question was doing as far as I could tell.

Comment: I understand, If you dont mind, the question I had written did not include all of the information as I was told by bck that it was too much knowledge, please look at the original post I made which contains all of the data and using the programming you displayed,  implement it. It really should not be much different as the program itself. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66681330/how-do-you-replace-segments-in-a-line-using-fileinput/66681817?noredirect=1#comment117876079_66681817

Comment: I've been stuck on this for days, I am so close to finishing but I'm completely stuck on this final part which isn't even mandatory I'm just doing it because I want to get the highest grade. I understand that you are not obliged to help but this really is one of those issues that are very easily solved its just that I don't have the knowledge yet to understand why this does not work.

Comment: Sorry, after looking at the latest version of your other question, I still don't understand what you're wanting to do. Using my code will not result in a completely blank page which your other question still claims after inserting my answer into it. IMO you probably shouldn't get the highest grade…

Comment: Im 16 so my grade boundaries are very low either way. thats why im able to make such mediocre code and still get a very decent grade. the idea of my runscan function is simple. I just want it to do calculations to a singular line one by one calculating it and if it is an integer "I.e if the counted coins are correct" the program will check to see if the file is written as Y for accurate or N for not accurate and if it isnt accurate, replace it with the correct Y or N.

Comment: Sounds like you need to incorporate a different kind of check within the `for line in fileobj:` loop that determines if the value on _each_ line needs to be changed or not. Just remember to always print each one, whether or not it was changed.

Comment: I think it has to do with the .join , is there a way to replace the words in a specific line, that is all im asking, I have spent 6 hours trying new things and trying to implement this because I know that there is a way I can do it and I am so close. Please help me and just edit the code you had previously presented so that it targets n line and only n line. I am begging at this point.

Comment: Yes, there are other ways to do it, but using `join()` is one of the easiest and I doubt its use is an issue. What do you mean by " targets n line"? Is it only "process n lines" or only "process the nth line" (leaving all the others unchanged in either case)?

Comment: the second, I was it to process the nth line and only replace the nth line